Power Apps: Hide Register Button and Show Unregister Button if Current User has Already Registered for a Course
I'm trying to set up a course registration app in Power Apps using two SharePoint lists. "Sessions" (which contains columns for the various course information such as Session ID", "Course Title",  "Start Time", "Location", etc.) and "Registration"(which contains user information such as "Registered User" (Person or Group column), "Department", "Phone", "Manager Name" and also contains the "Session ID" with the value from the "Session" list).
On the first screen I have a gallery showing the "Sessions" list, and want the user to be able to register for the course there. I have a "Register" button and an "Unregister" button, but want to be able to show the "Register" button if the current user has not registered for the course and show the "Unregister" button if the current user has registered for the course.  The code I'm using on the "Visible" property for "Unregister" button is as follows:
!IsBlank(LookUp(Registration,'Registered User'.DisplayName= User().FullName)) And !IsBlank(LookUp(Registration,'Session ID'=ThisItem.ID))

However, the "Unregister" button displays no matter whose name I enter for the "Registered User" field, I still see the "Unregister" button when I should only see that when it is my own name entered in that field.
For the "Register" button, I'm using the following code in the "Visible" property:
!IsBlank(LookUp(Registration, 'Registered User'.DisplayName <>User().FullName)) And (IsBlank(LookUp(Registration, 'Session ID'= ThisItem.ID))) And (ThisItem.Seats > 0)

However, it does not display for me if anyone is registered for the course (and gives me a delegation warning, which I would also like to avoid).
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've done a quick test of your formulas in my environment and your formulas seem to work as desired. Granted, my lists aren't identical to yours, but conceptually I think the formulas are fine. Can I suggest adding some troubleshooting labels to your app to check that your lookups are returning the correct information? e.g. add LookUp(Registration,'Session ID'=ThisItem.ID).ID to your Sessions gallery and see what the result is. Also, add LookUp(Registration,'Registered User'.DisplayName= User().FullName).ID to your app. This isn't a solution but may highlight some unexpected issue.

Thanks for the suggestion, user79408.

I gave it a try and found the first label (Lookup(Registration,'Session ID...)) returned the ID value from the Registration list, which are all unique and matched the ID of the items (in this case 94, 95 and 96(yes, I've done that many test registrations)), but the second label (Lookup(Registration,'Registered User'...)) also returned an ID value from the Registration list, but instead of unique values, they are all the same, which is the one where I used my own name as the 'Registered User' (95).

After a lot of trial and error, and with the great suggestion from user79408, I was able to determine that the correct formulas for the Visible property of the buttons should be as follows:
For the Register button:
(LookUp(Registration,'Session ID'=ThisItem.ID, 'Registered User'.DisplayName <> User().FullName)And ThisItem.Seats>0) Or (IsBlank(LookUp(Registration,'Session ID'=ThisItem.ID,'Registered User'.DisplayName <> User().FullName)) And ThisItem.Seats>0)

And for the Unregister button:
LookUp(Registration,'Session ID'=ThisItem.ID, 'Registered User'.DisplayName = User().FullName) Or !IsBlank(LookUp(Registration,'Session ID'=ThisItem.ID,'Registered User'.DisplayName=User().FullName)) And ThisItem.Seats>0

Then I added a label for when the course is full, but the current user is not registered for the particular course:
LookUp(Registration,'Session ID'=ThisItem.ID,'Registered User'.DisplayName <> User().FullName) And ThisItem.Seats = 0

This seems to work well so far.  I'm hoping this might help someone else that is struggling with this.
